# User in Laravel controllers

Tags: laravel, authentication, controller, laravel-5.3

I have a system in laravel 5.3 that uses over 40 controllers and probably 200 views.

I am attempting to clean up the code and use best practice. Given that certain calls are made pretty much everywhere, it makes sense to define it somewhere "semi globally". I would assume this would be in the `Controller` from which all controllers extend.

One object is `$user`, and has child `$user->organisations` and `$user->organisation->locations`.

Loading this at a base controller (or equivalent) way would also give me the advantage that I could ensure child relationships were eager loaded in an optimal way ensuring any `foreach` style code never results in multiple small database lookups. There are a number of other items I want to do this for with similar ramifications for database optimisation. These all use the `Auth::user()`, and they affect permissions with child objects.

Given that there are about 20 properties/variables of use to be shared (all dependant on `Auth::user()`) removing this duplicated code from almost every method is a huge improvement.

My aim is to be able to reference `$this->user` from any controller, and already have pre-loaded all the child/related objects.

Laravel 5.3 re-organised the loading order, so sharing the logged-in user data as part of `Controller::__construct` is no longer feasible.

Here's the code attempted so far:

In `Controller::__construct`

```
$this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
           $this->user = Auth::user();
           view()->share('user', $this->user);

            return $next($request);
    });
```

Unsurprisingly, this correctly sets the `$user` variable at View level, but not Controller level. While I do $user it at view level, this doesn't help.

Given that there are about 20 properties/variables of use to be shared (all dependant on `Auth::user()`) I decided that one Helper would at least move this into a centralised location. I instantiate the helper to be stored as property across all controllers : `$this->authentication_helper`

In an example controller: `SearchController` :

```
public function index(Request $request): View
{
    $this->authentication_helper->getAuthenticationData($this);
    //... logic for the search
}
```

With the `AuthenticationHelper` doing (amongst other things):

```
public function getAuthenticationData(Controller $controller) : void
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $controller->user = User::with(
        organisations.locations', // .. other children .. //
    )->find($user->id);
    // share to the view
    View::share('user', $controller->user);
    // ... other $controller property setting
    return;
}
```

I am unsure as to whether this is best practice.
*edit* - A previously raised second issue been solved - the main question remains:

Is there a problem with this approach - what would be an equivalent way of moving these 20 or so variable assignments to a higher level.

Comment: You can directly use global variable `auth()->user()` in controller and view too. So, you don't require to declare variable  `$user = Auth::user();` in 40 controllers and much more methods. and `$this->user->organisations` can be replaced with `auth()->user()->organizations` but, it will not help in eager loading.

Comment: Incorrect - the function returns null using the following:

`public function __construct()     
{
        $user = auth()->user();
        var_dump($user); exit;
}`

Comment: Then the request most likely didn't come from an authenticated user.

Comment: Yes it did. I'm logged in as admin. I'm authenticated. If you run `Auth:user()` in a controller method it works as expected, just not in the constructor (5.3+ laravel change and is working as expected).

Comment: If  `view()->share('user', $this->user)`; is causing `$user` to be present in your views then that would lead me to assume it is working. Firstly, I would suggest adding `dd($this->user);` underneath `$this->user = Auth::user();` and if you do get the auth user instance then I would check that you're not altering `$this->user` somewhere else after you've set it.

Comment: `$this->user = AUth::user(); view()->share('user', $this->user);` works, it's just that the *value* of `$this->user` is `NULL` if it is calculated inside a controller constructor. If I do that inside a non constructor method it works as expected. My point is that this is *expected* behaviour in Laravel 5.3+. I want to know a better way which doesn't require a declaration in every method (such as the constructor).

Answer (score 0):

You can get authorized user in controller using Laravel DI, simply your code should be something like this

```
YourControlle extends Controller
{
     public function test(Request $request)
    $user = $requset->user(); //use auth user 

}
```

Comment: This is interesting, but doesn't help with the main issue: I want to do this globally with 20 variables via a helper inside the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be a helper (or multiple helpers, you can create a `app\Helpers` namespace for that) and have all your logic within it.
The `Auth::user()` will be accessible from that helper using the **Auth** Facade, and have your logic there. 
An other simpler way is just extending your controllers from a custom base controller you make (which you're going to extend from **Controller**) and append a `$user` member to it with a protected visibility, and share it to the view, to be done with in the constructor or in a method to be called through `parent::magicMethod()`

**EDIT**
You can override the `callAction` method used by the controller class

```
/**
 * Execute an action on the controller.
 *
 * @param  string  $method
 * @param  array   $parameters
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function callAction($method, $parameters)
{
    // insert your logic here
    return call_user_func_array([$this, $method], $parameters);
}
```

The reason why you can't access the Auth via the constructor is because the session was not fired up yet. You can catch it when it does with this event listener :

```
    Event::listen(Authenticated::class, function ($event) {
        $this->user = $event->user;
    });
```

*not tested*

A middleware with a closure would do the work too. Make it have your logic, and use it in all your controllers.